# Visual Studio Code - 'Bash Debug' extension install fails

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I am used to very easily installing extensions in VSC. But now I want to install Bash Debug, and it fails.I get the error message *Failed to install 'rogalmic.bash-debug'.

Along with the error message, you get the option 'download manually'. I of course opened the resulting  .vsix code in VSC, but it did not lead to the code being installed.

Apparently, there is no log regarding this in VSC.

Comment: I get the same error when I attempt to install Python: Failed to install 'ms-python.python'.

Comment: extensionsActions.ts:265 Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
    at e.resolveAuthority (extensionHostManager.ts:282)
    at async F._scanAndHandleExtensions (extensionService.ts:305)
    at async F._initialize (abstractExtensionService.ts:411)